# How to add proto file in a non-grpc service project in VS 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, protocol-buffers

In a grpc service project, when I add a new item/file, I can select the file type as "Protocol Buffer File" and the "Build Action" (in file property) is "Protobuf compiler"

But when I have a non-grpc service project (say a class lib), there is no "Protocol Buffer File" type I can choose when I add a new file. Even I create a file with .proto ext, there is no "Protobuf compiler" in "Build Action" I can select.

Is there any way I can add a proto file in a non-grpc service project or I can only edit the project .csproj manually (I mean copy the xml node about the proto files from the grpc service project to a non-grpc service project)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want to do is possible.

The "Protobuf compiler" option you mentioned comes from the [Grpc.Tools Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Tools/), which uses the [protobuf compiler protoc](https://grpc.io/docs/protoc-installation/) to generate C# code. When you build a project and you want to generate code-behind files from the protobuf files during the build, you either need this package or a metapackage like [Grpc.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.AspNetCore), which holds a reference to it in the project. During the build, protoc then builds the code-behind files if you have a "Protobuf compiler" option set. Like you said, in the default "ASP.NET Core gRPC Service" project you have the "Protobuf compiler" option, that is because it has the *Grpc.AspNetCore* nuget package installed by default. EDIT: as mentioned by kzfid, the package *Google.Protobuf* is needed to compile the C# code that has been generated by protoc.

---

So, in short, what you have to do is: 1. Add the necessary nuget packages in the project where you want the "Protobuf compiler" options and 2. If the protoc files are in a different project than the project where you want to generate C# code, you have to add a project reference

**1. Install required Nuget Packages**

In any project where you want to create the code-behind c# files from the protoc files (and have the "Protobuf compiler" option for protoc files), you should install the following nuget packages:

```
Grpc.Tools
Google.Protobuf
```

or a package that references them like *Grpc.AspNetCore*. By adding these packages you will have the "Protobuf compiler" option for all proto files, even when they are referenced from a different project, like a shared class library.

**2. Add a project reference for proto files**

If you have a project where you want to create the code-behind files for proto files, but the *.proto files are in a different project, you have to add a reference. For example, if there is a **connections.proto** file in a namespace called **Protos** in a shared class library called **Shared**, and I want to use the generated code in a client project called **Client**, I have to install the nuget packages mentioned above in the client project, add a project reference in the client project for the shared class library and add the following in the Client.csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="..\Shared\Protos\connections.proto" GrpcServices="Client">
        <Link>Protos\connections.proto</Link>
    </Protobuf>
</ItemGroup>
```

Now there is the **connections.proto** file referenced in the client project and the "Protobuf compiler" options for it, but the file itself is located in a different project (the shared class library).

Comment: Exactly what I want. Thanks. Never aware of the compiler is inside the package (Thought it is a built-in one in IDE). {Grpc.Tools} is the compiler/code generator to generate the c# code and {Google.Protobuf} is the package needed for the generated c# code to be compiled. Just one thing, there is no .proto file template when I select "Add new item" even after my installing the packages and restarting the IDE. But not a big deal, I can change the "Build Action" in "File Property" later.